# 3 table many-to-many relationship

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I have 3 table

1. `Partcar`
2. `BarbellWheels`
3. `Assembly`

now, im confused how to manage this table to got connection, cause `Partcar` and `Assembly` is many-to-many relationship. But, `BarbellWheels` will merging with `Partcar` in `Assembly`. How to make this 3 table have many-to-many relationship, `Partcar` and `BarbellWheels` with `Assembly`.

EDIT :

there is 5 data on Partcar and must combine to 1 in Assembly and BarbellWheels will combine in Assembly with max 2 data on it. So, this is the link

[image: this is the diagram]

any advise? need some help here

EDIT : 
I forgot to mention the relationship between them. So, 2 tables `partcar` and `BarbellWheels` is Many-to-Many with `Assembly`.

Comment: Please explain what *"But, BarbellWheels will merging with Partcar in Assembly"* means. Or, what is the relationship between BarbellWheels and Partcar? What is the relationship between BarbellWheels and Assembly?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ so, BarbellWheels and Partcar is different database but will combine in Assembly, there is no relationship between BarbellWheels and Partcar, they just got combine in Assembly,

Comment: Can a BarbellWheel be related to many Partcars or just one? Can a Partcar be related to many BarbellWheels or just one?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ BarbellWheel 1 or many to Assembly cause Partcar must assembly 1st, Partcar many to many with Assembly, thats what im thinking. But, if i follow my supervisior, she said the Partcar and BarbellWheels will combine in Assembly. So, what do you think?

Comment: Your tables do not show the foreign keys that reference other tables.  In other words you have not implemented the relationships.